# Error in using instanceOf operator in Java

Tags: java, equals, instanceof

Not sure what is going wrong on line 24. I'm trying to override the Object.equals() method, but since that method takes type Object, I want to filter out inputs that are not an instance of Employee. This is for an intro java course

I'm getting these errors:

```
4 errors found:
File: /Users/wesley/Documents/Employee.java  [line: 24]
Error: ')' expected
File: /Users/wesley/Documents/Employee.java  [line: 24]
Error: variable declaration not allowed here
File: /Users/wesley/Documents/Employee.java  [line: 24]
Error: ';' expected
File: /Users/wesley/Documents/Employee.java  [line: 30]
Error: 'else' without 'if'
```

Here's the code.

```
//employee number, name, and salary
public class Employee{
  private String name;
  private final int ID;
  private double salary;
  private static int lastID;
  public Employee(String name, double salary){
    this.name=name;
    ID=Employee.lastID+1;
    this.salary=salary;
    Employee.lastID=Employee.lastID+1;
  } 
  public String getName(){return name;}
  public int getID(){ return ID; }
  public double getSalary(){ return salary;}
  public void setName(String newName){name=newName;}
  public void raise(double newSalary){ salary=newSalary;}
  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+ getName() + "\nID: " + getID() + "\nSalary: " + getSalary();
  }
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o){
    if(o instanceOf Employee){//errors are here!
    Employee input=(Employee) o;
    if(this.getSalary()==input.getSalary() && this.getName().equals(input.getName())){
      return true;
    }
  }
    else{return false;
    }//another error here
      }
    }
```

Can't be bothered to fix the indentation. Just happened when I pasted stuff in

Comment: Welcome to SO, the issue is there is no operand called `instanceOf` it is called `instanceof`.  As a side note I would flip the if condition to be `if (!(o instanceof Employee)) { return false }` you wont need the `else` clause and it will make things slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a number of things that you can improve.

First, the **instanceof** keyword is lowercase.

Second, if you override `equals(Object)`, you MUST also override `hashCode()`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/4121151). This answer also contains excellent examples of how to implement both `equals` and `hashCode`.

Third, your implementation allows `name` to be `null`, in which case `this.getName()` is `null` and your check

```
this.getName().equals(input.getName())
```

throws a `NullPointerException`. I suggest you follow the more robust practice in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2265637/4121151) or [this tutorial](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17), or make sure that `name` can never be `null`, by checking it in the constructor and `setName`.

## Additional improvements and remarks

If there is a field `ID`, I assume that it is there to *identify* the employee. In that case, *it must be included in the `equals` check*.

If there is an 'ID`, why also check the *name* and the *salary*? Does changing the *salary* also mean that it becomes a different *Employee*? Same if I correct the name of the *Employee*?

The initialisation of `ID` is not thread-safe, and can lead to different *Employees* having the same `ID`. Consider doing:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
///
private static AtomicInteger lastID = new AtomicInteger();
```

And in the constructor just do

```
this.ID = lastID.getAndIncrement();
```

which makes the following line unnecessary:

```
Employee.lastID=Employee.lastID+1;
```

Another thing is that the method `raise` also allows the salary to be set *lower* than its previous value. I would either check for that, or rename `raise` to `setSalary`.

Given all that, it would lead to something like:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Employee {
    private static AtomicInteger lastID = new AtomicInteger();
    private String name;
    private final int ID;
    private double salary;

    public Employee(String name, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        ID = lastID.getAndIncrement();
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }

    public int getID() { return ID; }

    public double getSalary() { return salary; }

    public void setName(String newName) { name = newName; }

    public void setSalary(double newSalary) { salary = newSalary; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Name: " + getName() + "\nID: " + getID() + "\nSalary: " + getSalary();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Employee)) return false;
        Employee employee = (Employee) o;
        return ID == employee.ID;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(ID);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the `AtomicInteger` is a little overboard :) personally.  The questions around `ID` are interesting, are two objects with the same id's but where the other fields have different values equal?  Anyway upvoted for the inclusion of implementing `hashcode` and the rather neat `equals` method :D

Comment: @Gavin maybe, but coming from a highly concurrent place it's kind of automatic. `ID=lastID++` also works, naturally.

Comment: thanks for your very detailed response! this was just a class example, but it's helpful to see all of these practical considerations :)

Answer (score 0):

It's `instanceof`, with a lowercase `o`, not "instanceOf" as you have it right now. After correcting this mistake, you can see that not all branches of the method have a `return` statement - what happens if the first `if` is entered but the second isn't?

Simplifying away boolean conditions and redundant `else` statements can solve this:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o){
    if (o instanceof Employee) { // instanceof instead of instanceOf
        Employee input=(Employee) o;
        return this.getSalary() == input.getSalary() && 
               this.getName().equals(input.getName());
    }
    return false;
}
```